# Communication link in radio Medium with OMNET++ and INET

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

In a Wireless environment and according to the wireless communication principle, the data is broadcasted to every node and only the designated node receives it. All other nodes ignore the data. (See the picture below)

[Picture : WSN communication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sftSs.png)

But for a particular needs, I want to hide all others data transmission links [**(WirelessSignal)Data**] as only the sink is receiving, i.e. I only want to see the link between the sender and the sink.

**How to disable the physical layer transmission in INET??**

I'm using the INET SensorNode module.

Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be precise: all nodes receive the packet in the communication range but only the destination node is passing it up from the link layer to the network layer. The rest of the nodes are receiving it also, but they are dropping it in the link layer. What you are after is to visualize communication on link layer (as opposed to the physical layer).

There are specialized visualizers in INET that display link layer activity. You [should use that](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/visualizer/canvas/datalinkactivity/doc/index.html).

At the same time, if the actual physical layer transmission is bothering you, you can switch that off in the Qtenv animation settings dialog. That way, you will see only the LinkLayer visualizer, but not the physical transmissions that broadcast to all nearby node.

Comment: Many thanks, @Rudi for your feedback. I realize that I was not enough clear. In fact, I was talking about the  **red strip**, how to appear only that one from the sender to the sink node and hide all others.  Thanks to your link, I saw this comment under the first example : **#This strip is the standard OMNeT++ animation for packet transmissions and has nothing to do with DataLinkVisualizer. When the packet is received in whole by wirelessDestination (the red strip disappears).** So this is related to OMNET++ and not INET.

Comment: In the case it is not feasible to do so, does it possible to make direct transmission (from one of the nodes to the Sink) in INET?

Comment: No. The whole INET infrastructure is based on the assumption that there is a *shared* access medium, so all nodes must receive the transmission, otherwise, how would they detect a packet collisions at all? The physical layer transmission cannot be filtered to show only the transmission towards the destination, because the decision that the packet is matching and must be passed up to the network layer will happen only later, long after the packet is actually received at the physical layer. By that time, all the animations are already happened. Physical layer transmission can be disabled though.

Comment: Updated the answer indicating that physical layer transmission can be disabled.

Comment: Thanks, @Rudi. You really lighted me with your kinds clarifications. **UPDATED QUESTION :** How to disable the physical layer transmission in INET?